# what is the relation between Cauchy sequence and convergent sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Can someone summarize all the cases of Cauchy sequence and convergent sequences?

I mean I know that:

1. Convergent sequence $\Rightarrow$ Cauchy sequence
2. Cauchy not necessarily $\Rightarrow$ Convergent sequence

what about divergent sequence?

is the following true?

3. Divergent sequence $\Rightarrow$ Not Cauchy sequence
4. Not Cauchy sequence not necessarily $\Rightarrow$ Divergent sequence

So what's true and what's not?

Comment: How do you define “divergent sequence”?

Comment: What you should try to remember is that bounded Cauchy sequences converge.  The only way convergence of a Cauchy sequence can fail (in the reals at least) is by escape to infinity.

Comment: The statement $3.$ is true since it is the contraposition of the statement $1.$ and as such has the same boolean value, meaning if one is true then so is the other.

Comment: @Bcpicao are you sure you don’t mean statement 4 rather than 3

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo, although, if the space is complete, it is the contraposition of the converse which is also a standard result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two cases you have listed here, the answer depends on in which space your working in.

In order to talk about a Cauchy sequence you need a metric. A space that is metric and in which all Cauchy sequences converge is called a **complete** metric space. Note that if a metric space is not complete it doesn't mean that a Cauchy sequence never converges, it only means that there is at least one case of a sequence that is a Cauchy sequence but does not converge. So, in a complete metric space convergence and Cauchy are equivalent attributes of a sequence, in a metric space that is not complete only the implication 1) is true.

This means for your listed cases:

3. is true in a complete metric space and not true in general in a not complete metric space. For in a not complete metric space there is at least one sequence that is divergent but also Cauchy (this ist he reason for it not being complete).
4. is true in every metric space. This follows directly from 1). For if there would be a not Cauchy sequence that converges, then it would contradict 1), which states that every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I don't know about metric spaces yet, the book said that the sequence that converges in $\mathbb{R}$ or in a subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ is a cauchy sequence but a cauchy sequence converges in $\mathbb{R}$ but not necessarily in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So could you elaborate on divergent sequences in the same context like in $\mathbb{R}$ and subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ or it not possible to do that without using metric spaces?

Comment: For reading what I wrote it maybe helps you t know, that $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space, but subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are not necessarily complete. So, when you read my answer you can replace "complete metric space" by "$\mathbb{R}$" and "not complete metric space" by "some subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot now it makes sense

Comment: If a Cauchy sequence does not converge in a subset $A \subset \Bbb{R}$ it converges to a number that is not in the set $A$. So, e.g. the open interval $(0, 1)$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$, but the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$, which converges to $0$ in $\Bbb{R}$ does not converge in the open interval since $0$ is not an element of it.

Comment: so can you check my understanding please : 1) convergent sequence is a cauchy always in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $A$  ;    2) cauchy sequence is convergent always in $\mathbb{R}$ but not always in $A$  ;   3)Divergent sequence is not cauchy in  $\mathbb{R}$ always but not always in $A$  ;      4) not cauchy sequence is divergent in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $A$ always

Comment: Yes, you got that right!

Comment: thanks a lot you can't understand how happy i am to finally understand it, God bless you!